# Google Analytics no me está funcionando fuera de Wordpress

Tags: php, html, google-analytics

Tengo una web que funciona en Wordpress y ahora la quiero migrar por partes a una plantilla propia, manejando el contenido desde esta plantilla combinada con código PHP puro.

He puesto los scripts de Google Analytics en el `<head>` de la página principal de mi nueva plantilla.

Estos son los scripts, hay dos, porque uno es una propiedad de Universal Analytics y el otro es la propiedad de Google Analytics 4:

```
<!-- Global Site Tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<link href="//www.googletagmanager.com" rel="dns-prefetch"/>
<link href="https://www.google-analytics.com" rel="preconnect" crossorigin/>
<script src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-***-1" async></script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag() {
    dataLayer.push(arguments);
}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'UA-***-1');
</script>


<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-***"></script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag() {
    dataLayer.push(arguments);
}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'G-***');
</script>
```

En la nueva plantilla no me está funcionando, a pesar de que el código de la misma sí muestra el contenido que genero de forma dinámica.

La forma de comprobar si funciona es viendo las visitas en tiempo real: si visito una URL de las que están en Wordpress la visita aparece en tiempo real, si visito una URL de mi nueva plantilla la visita no aparece.

Inspeccionando el código en la nueva plantilla no hay ningún error, todo sale igual que en la parte de Wordress y me sale el mensaje:

```
Successfuly preconnected to https://www.google-analytics.com/
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que me funcione?

Comment: Considera esperar 24 horas para que se indexe la informaciòn.

Comment: @Jorgesys puede ser eso. Esperaré entonces para verificar. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Inspeccionando la URL es Google Search Console encontré el problema, dejo aquí la respuesta por si puede servir a alguien más y de paso, descubrí el rastreador de Search Console como una herramienta importante de depuración. Pues la consola de mi navegador no me indicaba este error por ningún lado.

El error era cuando intentaba conectar al servicio de Google Analytics para enviar los datos, el script se estaba bloqueando porque estaba aplicando normas de seguridad `Content-Security-Policy`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; img-src 'self';
connect-src 'self' 
      https://www.mi-dominio.com; 
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 
      https://www.googletagmanager.com 
      https://use.fontawesome.com 
      https://cdn.polyfill.io 
      https://code.jquery.com 
      https://www.google-analytics.com          
      https://demo.creativebulma.net;
  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 
      https://cdn.jsdelivr.net 
      https://use.fontawesome.com;
  font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 
      https://use.fontawesome.com;
      ">
```

Este error lo puede ver al rastrear la URL en Search Console siguiendo estos pasos:

1. Seleccionar **Inspección de URLs** en el panel de la izquierda
2. Escribir la URL y **presionar Enter**. Entonces la URL se rastreará y aparecerá el resultado en el panel de contenido.
3. Seleccionar **PRUEBA EN TIEMPO REAL** en la parte superior derecha del panel de contenido.
4. Esté o no indexada la URL si la misma existe saldrá el resultado en verde. Seleccionar **VER PÁGINA PROBADA**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces aparecerá un panel en la parte derecha con varias opciones. Seleccionar **Mensajes de la consola de Javascript**, donde se puede ver el error antes mencionado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Código corregido

El mensaje es claro, simplemente hay que autorizar a Google Analytics agregando su URL en la directiva `connect-src`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; img-src 'self';
connect-src 'self' 
      https://www.mi-dominio.com
      https://www.google-analytics.com;
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 
      https://www.googletagmanager.com 
      https://use.fontawesome.com 
      https://cdn.polyfill.io 
      https://code.jquery.com 
      https://www.google-analytics.com          
      https://demo.creativebulma.net;
  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 
      https://cdn.jsdelivr.net 
      https://use.fontawesome.com;
  font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 
      https://use.fontawesome.com;
      ">
```

Nada más hacer esto, puedo ver las visitas en tiempo real, comprobando de este modo que los datos se están enviando a Analytics.